# WPF UserControl class library not showing in the editor (but ok at runtime)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, user-controls

I have created a project compiled as a class library (.NET Framework 4) in which I'm defining several "UserControl" objects that I intend to use as graphic elements in other projects.
Here an example of one of them:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfSinergoHMIControls.RoundedButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSinergoHMIControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Click="button_Click" PreviewMouseDown="Button_MouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="Button_MouseUp">
                <Button.Resources>

                </Button.Resources>
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Width="{Binding Size}"
                                Height="{Binding Size}"
                                BorderBrush="#FF3C7FB1"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                Name="RoundedButtonBorder">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#3a4451" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#0b2039" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="true">

                                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="RoundedButtonBorder">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush>#FF2C628B</SolidColorBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="RoundedButtonBorder">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#567db9" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#1f4486" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

please note that I'm not defining on purpose "width" and "height" of the element since I want to define it "dynamically" when I drag and drop the element inside the page.
If I use this element inside the same project it works fine.
Suppose now that I create a different project and I reference the former one by right clicking on the toolbox and browsing the ".dll". This results in all my custom "UserControl" objects appearing in the toolbox.
When I drag and drop my object into the page in the editor the object itself is not showing:
[image: editor]
when I run the same application my object is now shown:
[image: runtime]
I cannot understand the reason why and how to fix it.
Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Thank you very much

Comment: Probably because of `{Binding Size}`, the designer can't find it. Firstly, you shouldn't use `UserControl` in place of custom control. Secondly, for making *round* button in WPF it's enough to define custom style.

Comment: What is the point of applying a template to a `UserControl`?  Just make the `Button` the direct child of the `UserControl`.

Comment: @Sinatr If you are referring to `{Binding Size}` of `Border` I just tried to put a constant value but the issue is still there

Comment: Compiling the project as ".NET Framework 4.5.2" solves the problem...